# using $_get and readfile() to force download while obscuring file location

Tags: php

A while back I managed to put together a simple php script to force downloads of files using $_get to pull variables from the url. My script was pretty simple:

```
<?php
    $myvar1 = $_GET['myfn'];
    $myvar2 = $_GET['myct'];
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename = ' .$myvar1);
    header('Content-type: ' .$myvar2);
    readfile($myvar1);
?>
```

While this works well for the simple task of forcing downloads for files located in the same folder as the script by passing it the filename and the content type, I'd like to be able to obscure the path of the files as well. I was thinking I would do something like this:

```
<?php
    $myvar1 = $_GET['myfn'];
    $myvar2 = $_GET['myct'];
    $myvar3 = $_GET['mycur'];
    $filepath = '/downloads/' . $myvar3 '/' . $myvar1;
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename =' . $filepath);
    header('Content-type: ' .$myvar2);
    readfile($myvar1);
?>
```

I would then pass the filename (myfn), the content type (myct), and the subfolder (mycur) in the url and then hardcode the fact that the subfolder I'm passing (mycur) is a sub of the "downloads" folder (which is a sub of the root of the site). I would then place the php script in the root of the site and call it with the appropriate variables in the url. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Ariel in Denver

Comment: This is a fatal security hole.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal

Comment: once you get the security holes plugged, try ... `filename="' . urlencode(basename($filepath)) . '"'`

Comment: IMHO, the overall approach is rather flawed. URL obfuscation does nothing to prevent link sharing or search engines. Not to mention that you've just build a backdoor that allows any random stranger to download any random file your web server has permission to read. I also think you're confusing URLs with file system paths. A URL is just a public identifier that doesn't need to correspond to a physical path in your server's hard disk drive. I think you should put all your files somewhere *outside* the public document tree and tweak the script to only `readfile()` stuff from that exact location.

Comment: I really appreciate the comments. Before I go any further I want to address the path traversal issue. While I wish I were sufficiently savvy to know what to do after reading the owasp article, sadly I am not. To be honest, I'm getting confused. Is my original script (the simple one) suffering from the same security issue? Is there an easy fix? Is this just a matter of deploying .htaccess restrictions or is there something in the script or scripts that needs adjustment?